# MediaWiki Internal error on using liquipedia's skin

Tags: php, mediawiki, mediawiki-installation

I've been having the same errors with all of mediawiki's 1.31+ version on using liquipedia's skin.
It has been said that it will only work on 1.31 alone, while I installed version 1.31, I still have the same errors. The error says that:

[MediaWiki internal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf8aI.png)

Meanwhile, on my GlobalVarConfig.php file, this is the code on line 53:

[GlobalVarConfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXpgJ.png)

Comment: It appears to be complaining that a specific global option has not been set. But that is not caused by the section of code you have shown, that part only does the check and raises the error.

Comment: So I just have to add a try catch error?

Comment: Well you could of course try to catch the exception somewhere – but that is not necessarily going to fix the problem, the theme probably has a reason to check if this config variable is set … Figuring out why it is not set, and reading up on where and how that should be done, might be the more sensible option here.

Comment: Please do not includes of code, instead add the relevant code only, as explained in How to ask a good question.  You may wish to edit your question for clarity, since the  Screenshots refer to a southpedia skin. The error states that "LiquiFlowAlphaWiki" is  undefined. If you have since resolved this consider answering your own question to help others with the same issue.